# Precondition exception when intersecting polygons in CGAL

Tags: c++, computational-geometry, intersection, cgal, polygons

I am using CGAL to compute the area of the intersection of two convex polygons. A short demo code for doing this was posted in the accepted answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10502672/compute-intersection-area-of-two-polygons-with-cgal) question. However, when I modify that code to use the polygons that I am interested in, CGAL throws a runtime exception from deep in the CGAL::intersection() routine.

Here is a short example code, which is copy-and-paste from the SO question linked above, except that it uses my own polygons and it prints some diagnostics about each polygon to show that they are convex and use a CCW winding order.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <CGAL/Simple_cartesian.h>
#include <CGAL/Polygon_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Polygon_with_holes_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Boolean_set_operations_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Polygon_2_algorithms.h>


typedef CGAL::Simple_cartesian<double> K;
typedef K::Point_2 Point;
typedef CGAL::Polygon_2<K> Polygon_2;
typedef CGAL::Polygon_with_holes_2<K> Polygon_with_holes_2;
using std::cout; using std::endl;


int main(){
    bool IsSimple, IsConvex, IsClockwise;
    double Area;

    // Define the polygons. P is long and skinny, Q is 20 equally
    // spaced points around a circle of radius 0.025. The top-right
    // corner of P protudes into Q.
    int np=7;
    int nq=20;
    Point points[]={
        Point( 2.67905949256324049657e-02,-2.36307305336680428809e-02),
        Point( 2.19804738309115066386e-02, 1.25954939609798088895e-02),
        Point( 3.24142504626934169210e-03, 8.27109808759729503436e-03),
        Point(-7.07297020897392769712e-02,-1.31780902623212625713e-01),
        Point(-1.72945875771868884385e+00,-4.33625989924519217311e+00),
        Point(-5.64696462817379796206e+00,-2.91346747524371210147e+01),
        Point(-5.66016394049875870564e+00,-4.95259849820236013329e+01)};
    Point points2[]={
        Point( 2.50000000000000013878e-02, 0.00000000000000000000e+00),
        Point( 2.37764129073788424429e-02, 7.72542485937368662852e-03),
        Point( 2.02254248593736890571e-02, 1.46946313073118266929e-02),
        Point( 1.46946313073118284276e-02, 2.02254248593736890571e-02),
        Point( 7.72542485937368836324e-03, 2.37764129073788424429e-02),
        Point( 1.53080849893419158600e-18, 2.49999999999999979183e-02),
        Point(-7.72542485937368489379e-03, 2.37764129073788424429e-02),
        Point(-1.46946313073118232234e-02, 2.02254248593736890571e-02),
        Point(-2.02254248593736890571e-02, 1.46946313073118284276e-02),
        Point(-2.37764129073788424429e-02, 7.72542485937368923060e-03),
        Point(-2.50000000000000013878e-02, 3.06161699786838317201e-18),
        Point(-2.37764129073788424429e-02,-7.72542485937368402643e-03),
        Point(-2.02254248593736925266e-02,-1.46946313073118232234e-02),
        Point(-1.46946313073118318970e-02,-2.02254248593736890571e-02),
        Point(-7.72542485937369096533e-03,-2.37764129073788389734e-02),
        Point(-4.59242549680257437283e-18,-2.50000000000000013878e-02),
        Point( 7.72542485937368229171e-03,-2.37764129073788424429e-02),
        Point( 1.46946313073118214887e-02,-2.02254248593736925266e-02),
        Point( 2.02254248593736855877e-02,-1.46946313073118318970e-02),
        Point( 2.37764129073788389734e-02,-7.72542485937369183269e-03)};
    Polygon_2 polyP(points, points+np);
    Polygon_2 polyQ(points2, points2+nq);

    // Print some properties of polygon P. It is simple, convex, and CCW
    // oriented
    CGAL::set_pretty_mode(cout);
    cout << "created the polygon P:" << endl;
    cout << polyP << endl;
    cout << endl;
    IsSimple    = polyP.is_simple();
    IsConvex    = polyP.is_convex();
    IsClockwise = (polyP.orientation() == CGAL::CLOCKWISE);
    Area      = polyP.area();
    cout << "polygon P is";
    if (!IsSimple) cout << " not";
    cout << " simple." << endl;
    cout << "polygon P is";
    if (!IsConvex) cout << " not";
    cout << " convex." << endl;
    cout << "polygon P is";
    if (!IsClockwise) cout << " not";
    cout << " clockwise oriented." << endl;
    cout << "the area of polygon P is " << Area << endl;
    cout << endl;

    // Print some properties of polygon Q. It is simple, convex, and CCW
    // oriented
    cout << "created the polygon Q:" << endl;
    cout << polyQ << endl;
    cout << endl;
    IsSimple    = polyQ.is_simple();
    IsConvex    = polyQ.is_convex();
    IsClockwise = (polyQ.orientation() == CGAL::CLOCKWISE);
    Area      = polyQ.area();
    cout << "polygon Q is";
    if (!IsSimple) cout << " not";
    cout << " simple." << endl;
    cout << "polygon Q is";
    if (!IsConvex) cout << " not";
    cout << " convex." << endl;
    cout << "polygon Q is";
    if (!IsClockwise) cout << " not";
    cout << " clockwise oriented." << endl;
    cout << "the area of polygon Q is " << Area << endl;
    cout << endl;

    // Compute the intersection
    std::list<Polygon_with_holes_2> polyI;
    CGAL::intersection(polyP, polyQ, std::back_inserter(polyI));

    double totalArea = 0;
    typedef std::list<Polygon_with_holes_2>::iterator LIT;
    for(LIT lit = polyI.begin(); lit!=polyI.end(); lit++){
        totalArea+=lit->outer_boundary().area();
    }
    cout << "TotalArea::" << totalArea;

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output of the test program.

```
created the polygon P:
Polygon_2(
  PointC2(0.0267906, -0.0236307)
  PointC2(0.0219805, 0.0125955)
  PointC2(0.00324143, 0.0082711)
  PointC2(-0.0707297, -0.131781)
  PointC2(-1.72946, -4.33626)
  PointC2(-5.64696, -29.1347)
  PointC2(-5.66016, -49.526)
)


polygon P is simple.
polygon P is convex.
polygon P is not clockwise oriented.
the area of polygon P is 71.1027

created the polygon Q:
Polygon_2(
  PointC2(0.025, 0)
  PointC2(0.0237764, 0.00772542)
  PointC2(0.0202254, 0.0146946)
  PointC2(0.0146946, 0.0202254)
  PointC2(0.00772542, 0.0237764)
  PointC2(1.53081e-18, 0.025)
  PointC2(-0.00772542, 0.0237764)
  PointC2(-0.0146946, 0.0202254)
  PointC2(-0.0202254, 0.0146946)
  PointC2(-0.0237764, 0.00772542)
  PointC2(-0.025, 3.06162e-18)
  PointC2(-0.0237764, -0.00772542)
  PointC2(-0.0202254, -0.0146946)
  PointC2(-0.0146946, -0.0202254)
  PointC2(-0.00772542, -0.0237764)
  PointC2(-4.59243e-18, -0.025)
  PointC2(0.00772542, -0.0237764)
  PointC2(0.0146946, -0.0202254)
  PointC2(0.0202254, -0.0146946)
  PointC2(0.0237764, -0.00772542)
)


polygon Q is simple.
polygon Q is convex.
polygon Q is not clockwise oriented.
the area of polygon Q is 0.00193136

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'CGAL::Precondition_exception'
  what():  CGAL ERROR: precondition violation!
Expr: (m_traits.compare_y_at_x_2_object()(p, cv) == EQUAL) && compare_xy(cv.left(), p) == SMALLER && compare_xy(cv.right(), p) == LARGER
File: /usr/local/include/CGAL/Arr_segment_traits_2.h
Line: 706
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I do not understand what is causing the error. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have used CGAL, but I hate it. It's so opaque that it's hardly usable. I think its developers think there are veeery clever, but they made a thoroughly opaque API. Is there not some forum specifically for CGAL, where you can ask for help?

Comment: As it happens, CGAL [suggests](http://www.cgal.org/mailing_list.html) posting questions on SO using the CGAL hashtag. I could file a bug report, but I think it is far more likely that the problem is operator error than a CGAL bug.

Comment: Replace `CGAL::Simple_cartesian<double>` by `CGAL::Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel`. See [here](http://www.cgal.org/FAQ.html#inexact_NT)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce this error (using CGAL 4.9 on MacOS with clang++). As far as I understand, an uncaught exception of this type is not supposed to happen, in other words, you have uncovered a bug in CGAL. So, do file a bug report as instructed in the error message
–– the part that you didn't post (or perhaps didn't get because of a different version?):

> Explanation:  Refer to the bug-reporting instructions at http://www.cgal.org/bug_report.html
>
> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type CGAL::Precondition_exception: CGAL ERROR: precondition violation!
>
> Expr: (m_traits.compare_y_at_x_2_object()(p, cv) == EQUAL) && compare_xy(cv.left(), p) == SMALLER && compare_xy(cv.right(), p) == LARGER
>
> File: /usr/local/include/CGAL/Arr_segment_traits_2.h Line: 706

As far as I can see from that file, the function throwing splits a curve into two sub-curved given a split point. The pre-condition is that the split point lies on the curve and it not an end point. Clearly, whether this pre-condition is met or not is a matter of the caller, another CGAL routine. In other words, there is nothing wrong with your input. What's wrong is the CGAL implementation, or more precisely, its way of dealing with imprecision of the number representation used.

---

*Edit following sloriot's comment.*

If I replace

```
typedef CGAL::Simple_cartesian<double> K;
```

with

```
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel K;
```

and use the appropriate type for `Area` and `totalArea` (I simply used `auto` and `decltype(Area)`, respectively), the code compiles (you must link it against `libgmp` and `libmpfr`) and runs without crash, reporting

```
totalArea::0.000876944
```

Comment: Switching to `Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel` resolves my problem. Also, my output (from version 4.9) was verbatim, so it is strange that your output includes information that mine doesn't. I am on Linux and using g++, so perhaps that accounts for the difference.