# Compute intersection part of two self-intersection polygons with CGAL

Tags: cgal

When polygons are simple or relatively simple, like convex polygons, it is relatively easy to compute their intersection part and area. I refered to this post: [Compute intersection area of two concave polygons with cgal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10502672/compute-intersection-area-of-two-polygons-with-cgal).

But when polygons are concave or self-intersection, is there any way of computing the intersection part?

For example, the points sequences of complex polygons what I want to use are shown below(It doesn't work with the above post):

```
Point points[] = { Point(0,0), Point(0,1), Point(2,0), Point(0,-2), Point(0,-1), Point(2,-1)};
Point points2[] = { Point(1,1), Point(3,1), Point(3,-2), Point(1,-2) };
```

Maybe I should decompose self-intersection polygons into simple polygons before I do the intersection. I'm new to CGAL, and I tried myself to browse the help document of CGAL, but maybe I still miss some points.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is the inner and what is the outer areas of a self intersecting polygon? There is nothing special about concave polygons as long as they are simple with respect to computing their intersection with CGAL::intersection().